# read inner JSON Object delphi

Tags: json, delphi

I have these JSON Object , I read it well , But when i read oauth value i got an empty result ,

How I can read it ?

```
{
        "status": true,
        "message": "Success",
        "items": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Tesst1",
            "email": "Test1@tesst.Test",
            "image": "https://www.website.com/images/man.png",
            "created_at": "2017-08-24 09:18:15",
            "updated_at": "2017-08-24 09:18:15",
            "oauth": {
                "token_type": "abc",
                "expires_in": 1296000,
                "access_token": "jI5NiwiZXhGVzIjpbXX0.RaC3ixxUeyYnCB6vNlwKsdjf09UeOwUJlcKmKErmE_LTAeQ-4fm8iBOKqUgpikTkyB3ztDGf4DAsaeEjUMqH76jZdbPHnX0vr676dCXkEunWoDEB8sYiHz7XRVgQ5W0O9yybA93mPO_XyrWPibkGW7GLQOApRD605N0e6vw0v9Kb_WQBim7zjTNqoLM1fSjgKJezFqf9_s3KIqBc4bjsayYLl7duzo2fzRmWtnGFfbsgO6YcaIz8ezNtWbtixLRMKnJEj1-MluqjWubsbq_gTI6yiyyac3_oY22Ge0QDdCtljadgO7wRz5VT5aJkxmJRB90u0ovm0tpGzYOO_4giY-J5egpOptjt2VZbPeM-vWPEo4-c6NYMZx6WqxBHjkZwiKUsM-tufzl5P5lFRJ9V_rBUBHEiSonTAk9FVDAwjqLc6N_IC1lsFDEC_3NBy4",
                "refresh_token": "def502003e7826477c1072497ad66d7f11ea29e81a0fafef6223a63b6a0a3d18de71165afb9a340d10facca3ac7ee955aac5786a5c66a39cdf77e3f6449458e07271cbcde699aabf4d7f72dad10d586c37497216552f88460e50e9ea4944214984d5b23bac04b5f8265d132"
            }
        }
    }
```

If i read the **oauth** as a JSON Object I got an exception about unsupported conversion,

> conversion from TJSONObject to string is not supported

what is the wrong with my code ??

```
if JsonRespnse <> '' then
    begin
      jsonObiekt := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue
        (TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonRespnse), 0) as TJSONObject;
      try
        try
          LoginValue := jsonObiekt.get('status').JsonValue;
          LoginValueIsTrue := StrToBool(LoginValue.value);

          if LoginValueIsTrue = True then
          begin
            ItemsValue := jsonObiekt.get('items').JsonValue;
            if ItemsValue is TJSONObject then
            begin
              strIdValue := ItemsValue.GetValue<string>('id');
              // strOuthValue := ItemsValue.GetValue<string>('oauth');
              OauthValue := TJSONObject(ItemsValue).get('oauth').JsonValue;
              if OauthValue is TJSONObject then
                Memo1.Lines.Add('oauth : ' + OauthValue.value);
            end;
          end;
        except
          on E: Exception do
            ShowMessage('Read JSON : ' + E.Message);
        end;
      finally
        jsonObiekt.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
strOuthValue := ItemsValue.GetValue<string>('oauth');
```

Is not working because it’s not a string in the context of the TJSON* classes. The key oauth is an json object just like 'items'.

You can read the values of the oauth object like you did it with 'items.id'

```
 if OauthValue is TJSONObject then
 begin
   Memo1.Lines.Add('oauth : ' + TJSONObject(OauthValue).ToString);
   Memo1.Lines.Add('oauth.token_type: ' + TJSONObject(OauthValue).Values['token_type'].ToString);
 end;
```

Does this cover your question?

Comment: thank you for reply, but the problem is about how you get the oauth content in `OauthValue` ?

Comment: @Phillipp H. oauth is an object that in item object .

Comment: In my answer is an example that shows how you can read the values of the oauth object.

Comment: this is the question answer :

`OauthValue := ItemsValue.GetValue<TJSONValue>('oauth');`